# how to create symlink available from anywhere

Tags: server, 20.04, symbolic-link

How can I create symlink located at \\100 that points to /media so that when users enter `cd \\100` they get redirected to `/media` and it doesn't matter in which directory it was entered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `\\100` with the backslashes of all possible notations out of curiousity? I doubt it's possible with that specific name, unless you redefine `cd` itself to use a different function.

Comment: Are those backslashes literal? `cd \\100` in your typical shell would actually look for `\100`, since the first backslash escapes the second.

Comment: Should I ever encounter a system where a symlink is named like that, I would format all disks.

Comment: @frabjous because I'm trying to get one stupid program working. I explained about it in one of my previous [posts](https://superuser.com/questions/1713133/change-bash-to-replace-string-in-all-future-commands-or-edit-mssql-server-to-acc)

Comment: @muru It actually doesn't matter I just need symlink escaped or not. I need to somehow specify symlink outside of / because of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1713133/change-bash-to-replace-string-in-all-future-commands-or-edit-mssql-server-to-acc)

Comment: @paladin Yeah, I'm not happy about it as well but I don't see any other option at this point.

Comment: I've read your other post. Is this omega-software a windows software? If so, you should better install it within a Windows VM to avoid those problems.

Comment: @paladin Well it is a client software for windows. There's no server edition or something. All it supposedly needs is a MSSQL Server and since Ubuntu supports MSSQL I wanted to save some money on license and get bit more out of the hardware thanks to better OS. But yeah, it tries to do a network connection and Ubuntu isn't capable of doing that as it seems.

Comment: Ubuntu is able to do samba network, the network protocol of Windows.

Comment: @paladin already done. But the SQL server doesn't support saving to it or I'm just dumb.

Comment: The Ubuntu SQL server saves on the Ubuntu filesystem, in example: `/srv/sql/`. Your Ubuntu machine should have a hostname, in example: `ubuntu-sql-server`. You install samba onto your ubuntu machine and activate file sharing for directory `/srv/sql/`, make sure the samba file sharing user is the same (same username and same password) like in Windows. Now you should be able to open the file sharing directory of your Ubuntu machine via Windows over the samba "URL", like so: `\\ubuntu-sql-server`.